# How does C evaluate this expression? C pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I don't fully understand this, could someone help me evaluate the expression below? If message has `**` and length only has `*`, by using `*()`
are we dereferencing to `*message` and `length`? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    bool func(char** message, size_t* length)
    {
       *(*message + *length) = '\0';
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*(a + b)` is another way of writing `a[b]`. The statement above is equivalent to

```
(*message)[*length] = '\0';
```

`*message` is a `char*` string, and `*length` is a size. It sets the character at index `*length` to NUL.

There is no particular reason for the extra layer of pointers. It would be more normal to remove one `*` from each parameter and have the function be:

```
bool func(char* message, size_t length)
{
   *(message + length) = '\0';
}
```

Or, in other words,

```
bool func(char* message, size_t length)
{
   message[length] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the part inside the parentheses calculates an address, and then the NUL is stored at that address.

Let's unpack it

```
char *ptr = *message; // derefernce the pointer to pointer
size_t len = *length; // get the length by derefencing the pointer
char * new_ptr = ptr + len;
*new_ptr = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

`message` is a pointer to a pointer to a block of bytes (a string actually). `length` is a pointer to a size_t (some kind of non negative integer). The expression is decoded as follows:

`*message` is a pointer to the string

`*length` is a number, the value at which `length` is pointing at, probably the required length for the string, or the length at which the string will be truncated (judging from the whole expression behaviour)

`*message + *length` is in aritmethic pointer, a pointer that points to some location which is `*length` bytes away from the start of the string

`*(*message + *length)` is dereferencing the pointer. This is the actual character we are pointing at.

`*(*message + *length) = '\0'` This is storing a NUL byte at that location, thus,  terminating the string.

The function could be rewritten as this, to improve readability:

```
bool func(char** message, size_t* length)
{
   size_t len = *length;
   char *msg = *message;

   msg[len] = '\0';
}
```